# (simple) Probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

In a hospital, there are 96 patients with a certain disease. Among these patients, 63 are randomly selected to receive the new treatment that increases the cure rate of 0.2 to 0:45.

**a) What is the probability of cure?**

**b) What is the probability of a patient having received the new treatment, given that he was healed?**

I can't grasp the mathematical thought that I have to have in order to answer this, would help me a lot if I receive an explanation.

Comment: For a) it's asking you what the probability of any given patient being cured is, so if 63 have $p=0.45$ and 33 have $p=0.2$ what is $p$ on average?

Comment: For b), you want to use Bayes Theorem: $P(A|B)={{P(B|A)P(A)}\over {P(B)}}$.  In this case, $A$ is the event "the patient receives the new treatment," and $B$ is the event "the patient is cured".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- Of the $63$ selected, how many do you expect to be cured?
- Of the $96-63$ not selected, how many do you expect to be cured?
- Of the $96$ total, how many do you expect to be cured?
- What proportion of the $96$ do you expect to be cured?
- What proportion of those you expect to be cured come from the $63$ selected?